# different background color after implementing css entity code in content

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to implement the CSS entity code in content in react SCSS file I am getting the background colour green with black border and not able to set the background colour as black.

here is my code

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 29px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: -18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 17px;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1.5px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked{
    margin-top: -6px;
  }
  
  input[type=checkbox]:after,
  input[type=checkbox]::after {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    visibility: visible;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  input[type=checkbox]:checked:after,
  input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
    content: "\2714";
    padding: -5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 7px;
    padding: 1px;
  }
```

Comment: `background-color: black;`?

Comment: Hi @KonradLinkowski, I tried that its not working

Comment: What about `color: black`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, nope that's not working as well

Answer (score 1):

Using your CSS, and simplified it a little, here are the results.

The green and black styles must coming from another CSS source, as my example using your CSS does not show this?

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  transform: scale(1000%) translate(50%, 50%);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: #775273;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #775273;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  visibility: visible;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "\2714";
  background-color: #ffba03;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```